# How can I get my react native app to automatically refresh data?

Tags: postgresql, react-native

I am trying to update my react native app to fetch data from the backend every few seconds. Below is my code where I want the data in the transaction history table to update automatically. What is the best way to do this?

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { View, StyleSheet, ActivityIndicator, Text, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import TransactionShape from '../../data/model-shapes/Transaction';
import TransactionListItem from '../../components/wallets/TransactionListItem';
import CardStyles from '../../utils/styling/Cards';
import Colors from '../../utils/styling/Colors';


const keyExtractor = ({ id }) => id;

function renderTransactionItem({ item: transaction }) {
  return <TransactionListItem transaction={transaction} />;
}

const TransactionHistorySection = ({ transactions, isFetching }) => {
  return (
    <View style={CardStyles.sectionCard}>
      {isFetching ? (
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
      ) : (
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.sectionHeading}>Transaction History</Text>
          {transactions.length ? (
            <FlatList
              data={transactions}
              keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
              renderItem={renderTransactionItem}
            />
          ) : (
            <Text style={styles.growContainer}>No Transactions</Text>
          )}
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You coud use a `setInterval(function(){ fetch_something }, 3000);`
function to run the function to fetch your data on interval you want. then whenever the data change your flatlist will shown the new data